# How to make blured activity when loading gif appears?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an upload activity and a loading animation. I want to make activity blured(or lock, idk) while loading animation waiting for response about uploading. Something like I press upload button, animation appears, activity is locked, then app get response about uploading and animation is gone and activity become unblured. Is there a way to make it ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `alpha` and make the layout `clickable` so that other view remains lock behind this. **Show/hide** `RelativeLayout` to **show/hide** progress.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That ``alpha`` instruction helped me, thanks, but I didn't use clickable, what it is supposed to do ?

Comment: It's lock the view behind it. That means behind view doesn't respond to click/touch listener during progress.